# Oracle SQL, is it possible to use a user-defined datatype property in a nested select?

Tags: sql, oracle, object, return, subquery

I have a PL/SQL function that returns a datatype with a property start_date:

```
create or replace FUNCTION RETURN_OBJ
RETURN my_obj
IS
  obj my_obj;
BEGIN
   obj := my_obj(SYSDATE);
   RETURN obj;
END;

create or replace TYPE my_obj
AS OBJECT (
start_date DATE
);
```

I can make use of the property in a simple SELECT statement e.g.

```
select RETURN_OBJ().start_date FROM DUAL
```

However when I try to use a virtual table (e.g. to avoid multiple function calls) I get an error:

```
select obj.start_date from (select RETURN_OBJ() AS obj FROM DUAL)
ORA-00904: "OBJ"."START_DATE": invalid identifier
```

Am I using the wrong syntax, or is this just not possible?
(By the way I'm using Oracle 11 although the customer is still on 9)

Thanks very much.

Comment: You are misusing the term **OBJECT**. IN Oracle, a function can return any supported _datatype_ (which does not include _objects_ as you would see in other environments, like JAVA).

Comment: Thanks FDavidov for the clarification (I've edited the question). However the problem remains - returning my_obj from a function works fine in the simple select - the problem is with the nested select.

Comment: Now I see... NO IDEA!!! Sorry.

Comment: `select obj from (select RETURN_OBJ() AS obj FROM DUAL);` works but when you try acces atribute it not works. That's interesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Brackets :-)

```
select (obj).start_date from (select RETURN_OBJ() AS obj FROM DUAL)
```

Comment: It is the very first time I see this `(obj).start_date` syntax. Is it somewhere documented at Oracle?

Answer (score 2):

You must use a table alias when you like to access functions from OBJECT Types. Try this one:

```
SELECT t.obj.start_date 
FROM (SELECT RETURN_OBJ() AS obj FROM DUAL) t;
```